# How to set environment PATH

Tags: ionic-framework, path, ionic2, environment

I face this problem when I run ionic serve command then show ionic is not internal or external command I just change the PATH

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin
```

Now ionic serve not working what is the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have overwritten the previous PATH variables that ionic was depending on. Here is a good [reference for path ionic path variables](http://www.tiagoporto.com/blog/environment-setting-tutorial-ionic-android-on-windows/)